# Visual Studio 2017 Mark duplicate names like in Sublime

Tags: visual-studio

I need to have a CTRL + D function from sublime text 3. In sublime when u click once on ex. radius it shows any others same radius fields in opened file, and u can press CTRL + D to mark first closest radius and later edit two selected fields, by next pressing u can edit 3 etc. etc. I need to have that function in Visual Studio 2017.

[image: grey = selected fields ready to edit in the same time]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining two visual studio extension, [Match Margin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MatchMargin) for highlighting the textual matches, [Multi Edit Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode) for editing in multiple places at the same time.